# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java

I am new to programming and my below code won't compile, not sure why that is. The program is supposed to take multiple command line arguments, parse them to doubles, and add them to the currentBalance. If, however, there is a string command, such as "sub" for subtract, it is supposed to take that string, with the doubles before and after to be calculated and then added to current Balance. any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    // ends program if no input given
    if(args.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    // starting balance
    double currentBalance = 500;
    int location = args.length; //stores count of CLIs into location 
    int penaltyFlag = 0;
    double op1 = 0;
    double op2 = 0;
    String operator = "";
    

    
    //Test to make sure that inputs can be parsed, would throw exception if can't parse anything
     for(int i = 0; i < location ; i++){
                    // test to see if next arg is double or operator
                    // if next arg is an operator then take arg and do operation 
                    if(isValidDouble(args[i]) && isValidOperator(args[i+1])){ 
                        //input must be a valid operator to continue here
                        operator = args[i];
                        op1 = Double.parseDouble(args[i-1]);
                        op2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+2]);
                        currentBalance += operation(op1, op2, operator);
                        System.out.println("Your balance: $" + currentBalance);     
                    } 
                    // if next operator is a double, add this arg and continue
                    else if(isValidDouble(args[i])){
                        double singleOperand = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
                        currentBalance += singleOperand;
                        System.out.println("Your balance: $" + currentBalance);
                    } }
```

Comment: In the case where the first arg passes isValidDouble() and the second passes isValidOperator(), which would be the first iteration of the loop when i=0, this line will attempt to index out of bounds: op1 = Double.parseDouble(args[i-1])  because index becomes -1.  In addition, the next line: op2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+2])  will index off the end of the array if there are only 2 arguments given.  You will need to add more checking to prevent these cases.

Comment: Your error is during running, not compiling. Does your IDE or log not show you which line  of code the error occurred on? This information should help you solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in "op2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+2]);", that "i+2" will be greater than args.length and cause outofbound exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are getting this error because you access values out of `args` that are not within the bounds of `args`. What I mean is that in the for loop, you are looping from `i = 0` to `i < location`. However, in this for loop you are calling `args[i-1]`, `args[i+2]`, and `args[i+1]`.

This means that when `i` is 0 (the for loop just started), you are asking `args` for its values at `args[0-1]` = `args[-1]` which is not valid. Regarding `args[i+2]` and `args[i+1]`, when the for loop is ending and `i = location - 1` (the last value when `i < location`), you are calling `args[(location - 1) + 1]` and `args[(location - 1) +2]`, which would both evaluate to indices that do not exist in `args` because you define `location` to be the length of args. Here's a picture describing what I mean:

[image]